# Make set of left & right overflow DIVs responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have this HTML and CSS

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.tile-container {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.div {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: -100%;
  margin-right: -100%;
}

.outer {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 9px 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #EB6C5D;
  width: 140px;
  margin-right: 2px;
  margin-left: 2px
}

.inner {
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  color: black;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Timeline</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class='tile-container'>
    <div class='div'>
      <div class='outer'>
        <div class='inner'>WEEK1</div>
      </div>
      <div class='outer'>
        <div class='inner'>WEEK1</div>
      </div>
      <div class='outer'>
        <div class='inner'>WEEK1</div>
      </div>
      <div class='outer'>
        <div class='inner'>WEEK1</div>
      </div>
      <div class='outer'>
        <div class='inner'>WEEK1</div>
      </div>
      <div class='outer'>
        <div class='inner'>WEEK1</div>
      </div>
      <div class='outer'>
        <div class='inner'>WEEK1</div>
      </div>
      <div class='outer'>
        <div class='inner'>WEEK1</div>
      </div>
      <div class='outer'>
        <div class='inner'>WEEK1</div>
      </div>
      <div class='outer'>
        <div class='inner'>WEEK1</div>
      </div>
      <div class='outer'>
        <div class='inner'>WEEK1</div>
      </div>
      <div class='outer'>
        <div class='inner'>WEEK1</div>
      </div>
      <div class='outer'>
        <div class='inner'>WEEK1</div>
      </div>
      <div class='outer'>
        <div class='inner'>WEEK1</div>
      </div>
      <div class='outer'>
        <div class='inner'>WEEK1</div>
      </div>
      <!-- Repeated '.outer' DIVs -->
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

This css trick, `.div { text-align: center; margin-left: -100%; margin-right: -100%;}`, makes the `.outer` DIVs aligned center and overflow to both left and right, if there are enough number of them. This is fine for a maximized desktop browser window.

When the **window width reduces**, at some point the `.outer` DIVs makes into the **next line**, which makes this not responsive.

I've tried `white-space: nowrap` on `.tile-container`, which solves above problem but now the `.outer` DIVs are **not centered**.

Please advice any CSS tricks to solve this issue, without any script.

Comment: I thought the trick to center a `<div>` is to use `margin: 0 auto;` or  `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;` https://jsfiddle.net/82ya72a4/

Comment: @caramba `margin-left:-100%,margin-right:-100%,text-align:center` in `.div` and `overflow:hidden` in `.tile-container` makes the tiles center align with overflow hidden to both **left & right**. `margin: 0 auto` makes extra tiles in next lines. Then added `white-space:nowrap` in `.tile-container`, but tiles are left aligned now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for "*DIVs makes into the next line*" was assigning '-100%' to left&right margin of `.div`. This means that each margin will be equal to the width of `.tile-container` which is parent of `.div`, NOT the width of '.div' itself. Then the following happens when browser width is reduces,

- `body` width reduces
- then `.tile-container` width reduces
- then `.div margin-left margin-right` reduces
- then computed width of `.div` reduces
- then the whole tiles(`.outer` elements) won't fit into `.div`
- then the tiles makes to new line

So the only way (that's what I found), is to assign the `left/right margin >= the total width`(including padding and margin) of all the `.outer` divs.

In my case, the number of tiles changes (max on load). So the **left/right margin can't be assigned in CSS**.

Done following jQuery code for this

```
var width = 0;
$('.outer').each(function() {
            width += $(this).outerWidth( true );
});
$('.div').css('margin-left','-'+width+'px');
$('.div').css('margin-right','-'+width+'px');
```

And changed css

```
.div {
    text-align: center;
    /*margin-left: -100%;
    margin-right: -100%;*/
}
```

**NOTE** : The script must be called only after page is loaded. In case of angularjs, after the view rendered.

Comment: Will wait for some time before accepting my own answer for anyone to come with a better solution to "**make tiles center aligned with overflow to left and right and still responsive**".